# Problem to get cookies at the remote server

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, cookies

Does anyone know why I cant get cookies from the remote server with the code below?

```
<?php 

    $inputCookie    =   JFactory::getApplication()->input->cookie;
    $value          =   $inputCookie->get($name = 'hotsiteX', $defaultValue = null);
    $mark = 0;

    if ( is_null($value)  ): ?>

        "html code"
        <?php $mark = 1;
              $inputCookie->set($name = 'hotsiteX', $value = 'accessed', $expire = time() + (100));         

    endif; ?>

?>
```

$cookieValue is always empty, I checked and its already set on my browser, besides, it also works perfectly on localhost.

I already tried `!isset($_COOKIE)` and `print($_COOKIE)`, its always empty at the remote server.

Answer (score 4):

Below should work for you. This was taken from [This Answer][1]

```
//GET JOOMLA COOKIES
$inputCookie  = JFactory::getApplication()->input->cookie;

//GET SPECIFIC COOKIES DATA
$value        = $inputCookie->get($name = 'MyCookieName', $defaultValue = NULL);

//CONDITIONAL STATEMENT TO RETRIEVE OR SET A COOKIE
if(is_null($value)){
    //SET YOUR COOKIE IF IT DOES NOT ALREADY EXIST
    $inputCookie->set($name = 'MyCookieName', $value = 'TestCookieVal', $expire = 0);
    echo 'NO COOKIE EXISTS, CREATING NEW COOKIE';
}else{
    //DO SOMETHING WITH YOUR COOKIE DATA IF IT ALREADY EXISTS
    echo $value;
    echo 'COOKIE EXISTS';
}
```

Comment: now can print the $value and see that it has the cooked i that i put, but when i  try to verify its value, it always returns that its empty.
empty($value)  always return true.

Comment: empty() is looking to see if the $value either does not exist or is false. Check your $value with something like this: ((isset($value) && $value === 'myvalue')?'true':'false')

Comment: Ok, i'll try it. Do you have any ideia why it works on localhost but not on the remote server.

Comment: Not a clue on that one. Possibly server setup?

Comment: I realized that the method $inputCookie->get returns empty or null if i didnt use the method $inputCookie->set before printing it.

Comment: Sounds like you got it figured out. If my answer has helped you sort this out please be sure to mark it as accepted.

Comment: my problem isn't solved, i still cant get a cookie that i didn't set on a previous session.

Comment: So you're trying to retrieve a nonexistent cookie?

Comment: My browser recognizes it, its an existing cookie, but the  remote application isn't getting it.

Comment: Test for your cookie with my edited answer above. I just tested this on my demo site and it works perfectly. Just be sure to swap out MyCookieName for the actual name of your cookie, and TestCookieVal to whatever you want the default to be when setting the cookie. You will wanna modify the expire value as well if you want the cookie to only last a specific amount of time.

Comment: I tested it, and its only working at the localhost. I printed mark and its always showing value 1 on the remote host, proving that the cookie i'm getting is always null.I edited my post to show the code i'm using now.